# In ios10, how can I get end call delegate method, even if app is background or suspended?

Tags: ios10, callkit

In ios10, Callkit framework can catch the call start and end. Is it available even if the app is background or suspended? And how can I get it?

Answer (score 1):

While your CallKit app has one or more calls ongoing, the system will ensure your app is not suspended and you will continue to receive CXProvider delegate callback methods as well as be able to request CXActions for those calls.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable background modes for VoIP and Audio options.